# How to make reusable component with optional props.onBlur function in react JS?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components

I have a TextField component

```
return (
    <TextField 
        label={props.label} 
        name={props.name}
        placeholder={props.placeholder} 
        type={textFieldType === 'password' ? props.type : textFieldType}
                    
        onBlur={(event) => props.handleOnBlur(event)} //after focus lost
        onChange={(event) => props.handleOnChange(event)}   //
        
        value={props.value}
    ></TextField>
)
```

Use the TextField component

```
//FirstName
<MyTextField
    type={inpValues.firstName.type}
    label={inpValues.firstName.label}
    name={inpValues.firstName.name}
    placeholder={inpValues.firstName.placeHolder}

    handleOnChange={
        (event) => {console.log('onChange called =' + event.target.value)}
    }

    value={inpValues.firstName.value}
    >
</MyTextField>

//Email Address
<MyTextField
    type={inpValues.email.type}
    label={inpValues.email.label}
    name={inpValues.email.name}
    placeholder={inpValues.email.placeHolder}

    handleOnBlur={
        (event) => {console.log('onBlur called =' + event.target.value)}
    }
    handleOnChange={
        (event) => {console.log('onChange called =' + event.target.value)}
    }

    value={inpValues.email.value}
    >
</MyTextField>
```

I want to call `handleOnBlur` only specific TextField. I don't want to call for all the TextField

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this optional in the prop, and then on your textfield only run the function if it's provided, something like this:

```js
return (
    <TextField 
        label={props.label} 
        name={props.name}
        placeholder={props.placeholder} 
        type={textFieldType === 'password' ? props.type : textFieldType}
        onBlur={(event) => {
          if (props.handleOnBlur) {
            props.handleOnBlur(event)
          }
        }} //after focus lost
        onChange={(event) => props.handleOnChange(event)}   //
        
        value={props.value}
    ></TextField>
)
```